# How can I strip data from the list python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, strip

[I just want to keep the years and not the numbers in present in the bracket.][1]

[This is my current output. I want to strip the data which is in the bracket and do this for all the data present in the list till the end][2]

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q9Wg.png

[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOVQO.png

Comment: Please post your code as code and not as images

Comment: Use ```split()```

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by using regex expressions.

```
import re  # Import
reg = "[\(\[].*?[\)\]]"  # Regex Expression
stripped_title = [re.sub(reg, "", i) for i in title]
print(stripped_title)


##2nd Case
stripped_title = [re.search('\d+', i).group(0) for i in title]
print(stripped_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()` function.

```
striped_titles = titles.split(",")
```

So, now  you can access each element from new list `striped_titles`